# How to center the ion-button inside ion-item?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

How should I center ion-button inside ion-item?

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-button>Sample</ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I tried some class from [CSS Utilities](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities) but with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

CSS:

```
.center-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-item: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <div class='center-button'>
       <ion-button>Sample</ion-button>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe just using block expand:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-button expand="block">Sample</ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS margin: auto

```
.margin-auto {
  margin: auto;
}


<ion-item>
 <ion-button class="margin-auto">Sample</ion-button>
</ion-item>
```